# React Apollo - Unsubscribing from queries

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm follow Apollo's [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/subscriptions.html#subscribe-to-more) on subscribing to data from my database using the `<Query>` component and the `subscribeToMore` function.

I've managed to get everything running correctly however i'm having issues with data being returned from a subscription even after the queries variables change.

Here is my code:

**main.js**

```
const DETAILED_CONVERSATION_QUERY = gql`
  query CONVERSATION_QUERY($convoId: ID!){
    detailedConversation(convoId: $convoId) {
      messages(last: 200) {
        text
      }
    }
  }
`;

const DETAILED_CONVERSATION_SUBSCRIPTION = gql`
  subscription($convoId: ID!) {
    detailedConversation(convoId: $convoId) {
      node {
        messages(last: 1) {
          text
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

<Query
  query={DETAILED_CONVERSATION_QUERY}
  variables={{ convoId: activeConversationId }}
>
{({subscribeToMore, loading, error, data }) => {
  if (loading) return <div className="chat-overlay__convo-details__loading" />
  const { messages, id, users } = data.detailedConversation;                          
  return (
    <Conversation
      id={id}
      subscribeToNewMessages={() => subscribeToMore({
        document: DETAILED_CONVERSATION_SUBSCRIPTION,
        variables: { convoId: activeConversationId },
        updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
          if (!subscriptionData.data) return prev;
          const newConvoDetails = subscriptionData.data.detailedConversation.node;
          const { messages } = subscriptionData.data.detailedConversation.node;
          const dataToReturn = Object.assign({}, newConvoDetails, {
            messages: [ ...prev.detailedConversation.messages, ...messages]
          })
          return {detailedConversation: { ...dataToReturn }};
        }
      })}
      messages={messages}
      setConversationId={this.setConversationId}
      chatOverlayActive={chatOverlayActive}
    />                            
  )
}}
</Query>
```

**Conversation.js**

```
class Conversation extends PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.subscribeToNewMessages();
  }
  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

What basically happens is there is a conversation id (`activeConversationId`) that refers to a conversation in my database which is what it subscribes to. When the user selects a different conversation the `activeConversationId` changes and the Conversation component mounts again with the new conversation.

My issue is that once I mount a certain conversation and then switch to another, it does not seem to unsubscribe from the previous one. My understanding was that when the variables in the `<Query>` component change then it would automatically unsubscribe me from my previous subscription.

The Apollo docs are good but a little vague when it comes to covering how unsubscriptions are handled so it would be great if anyone else who may have had a the same issue could shed some light.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was resolved by completely re-rendering the `<Query>` component again. It does not seem to unsubscribe by just changing the variables in the query.

Comment: Wouldn't changing the variables of the query, trigger the re-render anyway?

Comment: i am also facing same issue, how to re-rendering the <Query> component again?